# Flutter - issue loading Emscripten JS library in a plugin

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web, emscripten

I'm working on a multi-platform plugin for exposing Csound API to Dart.
For the web part, it is using a Javascript file generated with Emscripten (CsoundObj.js) and another one (CsoundDart.js, mostly glue upon CsoundObj.js).
The dart side is a simple wrapper using package:js.
I tested in a Flutter app, loading Javascript files from index.html ... and it works fine.
In the plugin project, I load the Javascript files from assets with

```
html.document.body.append(html.ScriptElement()
   ..src = "assets/packages/csounddart/assets/CsoundObj.js"
   ..type = "text/javascript"
   ..defer = true
);
```

I make this manipulation for both files. Unfortunately, while the second file (CsoundDart.js) seems to load properly, the `CsoundObj` class is undefined, and I get the following error from CsoundDart.js : `ReferenceError: CsoundObj is not defined`.
I can confirm (I tested with another dummy file) that it is not a scope question (CsoundDart.js can access scope from other files dynamically loaded like showed above).

I already asked this question on Dart side here : https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46851

Did anyone already experienced it ? How does Flutter plugins manage those dynamic loads ordering ?

Comment: Hi @Philiste, I have a similar use case, have you got the solution about this issue?

Comment: No, I didn't have time to go further in this project. Though, my different tries didn't produce any working result.